# Laravel 5 return datetime with timezone

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, php-carbon

I am building an API and I would like to return all my timestamps like created_at, deleted_at, ... and so on as complex objects including the actual datetime, but also the timezone. 
I am already using {Carbon/Carbon}in my Controller. I defined my date field in the model as well.
When I access the date fields in my controller, I actually get Carbon objects. But when I return my result set as JSON, I only see the datetime string. Not the timezone.

**Current JSON**

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "username": "purusScarlett93",
    "firstname": null,
    "lastname": null,
    "language_id": 1,
    "pic": null,
    "email": null,
    "authtoken": "f54e17b2ffc7203afe345d947f0bf8ceab954ac4f08cc19990fc41d53fe4eef8",
    "authdate": "2015-05-27 12:31:13",
    "activation_code": null,
    "active": 0,
    "devices": [],
    "sports": []
}
```

**My wish :)**

```
{
  "id": 4,
  "username": "purusScarlett93",
  "firstname": null,
  "language_id": 1,
  "pic": null,
  "email": null,
   "authtoken":"f54e17b2ffc7203afe41d53fe4eef8",
   "authdate": [
     {
       "datetime": "2015-05-27 12:31:13",
       "timezone": "UTC+2"
     }
   ],
   "activation_code": null,
   "active": 0
 }
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: I believe you could do this by changing your authdate accessor, but be aware that would change the access of your date in your whole application. For a more specific change on your particular API call you could handle this in your controller, or by a display class that takes the carbon object and generates the 2 item array you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because all `Carbon` objects have a `__toString()` function which is being triggered when you try to convert the object into a string (i.e. JSON). Try to see if you can create your own accessor on your model that gives you a custom array instead of a string.

```
public function getAuthdateAttribute(Carbon $authdate) {
   return [
           'datetime' => $authdate->toDateTimeString(),
           'timezone' => 'UTC' . $authdate->offsetHours
          ];
}
```

As user Alariva points out, this method will override your default way of accessing `authdate`; so if you want to access your original `Carbon` object maybe you'll have to create a special method for that.

Or you could be a bit clever and do something like this:

```
public function getAuthdateAttribute(Carbon $authdate) {
   return [
           'datetime' => $authdate,
           'timezone' => 'UTC' . $authdate->offsetHours
          ];
}
```

Then to access the original object: `$carbon = $this->authdate['datetime']`

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a function like this inside your model:

```
public function getAuthDateAttribute() {
  return [
   "datetime" => "2015-05-27 12:31:13",
   "timezone" => "UTC+2"
 ];}
```